# Can talend migrate serialized data from MYSQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-migration, talend

We are using [Barebone CMS' SSO](https://barebonescms.com/documentation/sso/)

The **MYSQL** database which we have, contains user's profile fields in serialized format under ***info column*** in ***users*** table.

**E.g.** **info column value**
`a:41:{s:7:"aboutme";s:0:"";s:7:"address";s:4:"Pune";s:11:"agriculture";s:11:"Agriculture";s:13:"agri_business";s:0:"";s:22:"agri_finance_insurance";s:0:"";s:12:"agri_trading";s:0:"";s:14:"agro_chemicals";s:14:"Agro Chemicals";s:10:"alt_energy";s:0:"";s:13:"ani_husbandry";s:0:"";s:6:"avatar";s:0:"";s:13:"biotechnology";s:0:"";s:4:"city";s:4:"Pune";s:18:"contact_first_name";s:0:"";s:17:"contact_last_name";s:0:"";s:7:"country";s:5:"India";s:11:"designation";s:0:"";s:5:"email";s:24:"amolXXXXXXX@gmail.com";s:8:"farm_act";s:0:"";s:12:"farm_service";s:0:"";s:10:"first_name";s:4:"Amol";s:6:"Gender";s:4:"Male";s:12:"horticulture";s:0:"";s:14:"interest_other";s:8:"Software";s:10:"irrigation";s:0:"";s:17:"KISAN2015_barcode";s:6:"577535";s:16:"KISAN2015_status";s:5:"green";s:8:"landline";s:0:"";s:9:"last_name";s:7:"Chakane";s:9:"lattitude";s:6:"18.482";s:8:"location";s:90:"Tukai Darshan Tekdi Rd, Bijle Nagar, Kale Padal, Hadapsar, Pune, Maharashtra 412308, India";s:9:"longitude";s:6:"73.944";s:13:"machine_tools";s:0:"";s:6:"mobile";s:14:"+91-95XXXXX478";s:10:"occupation";s:27:"Farming,Certification,Other";s:16:"occupation_other";s:18:"Software Developer";s:11:"org_farming";s:0:"";s:12:"post_harvest";s:0:"";s:17:"registration_type";s:5:"email";s:5:"state";s:11:"Maharashtra";s:8:"username";s:24:"amolXXXXXXX@gmail.com";s:7:"website";s:0:"";}`

We wish to migrate them into **PostgreSQL** in different tables.

**E.g.** We have user's interest, which has values stores **"agriculture, dairy, poultry"**. They are stored in serialized format in info column of user table.

In PostgreSQL, we have master table created for interests which stores all types of interests say **agriculture, dairy, poultry**. And then ***user_interest*** table will have ***interest_id***, ***user_id*** columns.

We are planning to use **Talend** to migrate this data from MYSQL to PostgreSQL.

Is it possible to achieve such data migration using Talend?

or

Should we go ahead with traditional way of writing PHP script?

or

What is the best way to migrate such data?

Thanks

Comment: How is it encrypted? The example you show is not encrypted in any way at least.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Is there a provision in Talend to deserialize and then migrate?

Comment: Unfortunately I have never heard of Talend before this so can't say what it can do.

Comment: So, what do you recommend? What will be the best way to migrate such data?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, it's just text. Database doesn't care, just dump and reload. But to change the structure you have to change the application using it also.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I am not worried about the application right now, we are anyway creating different application from scratch. The most important thing is migration of data. Seems, will have to write custom PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

The example you show is not encrypted in any way. It is just a serialized version of a PHP data structure. Database doesn't care a bit about that, it will just store the string that is given to it.

If you want to change the data to be stored in a different way you'll have to handle that yourself since it's all about the application storing the data in the database. So it's up to you to make the application using this data to use it in a separated way and also up to you to separate the data from the serialized string.

Answer (score 0):

Talend connects directly to MySQL via a connector it will pull the data in a tabulated format and store in PostgreSQL if you configure it correctly it is a feature rich java development GUI and quite frankly it would eat this issue for breakfast,

I currently use talend to pull data from 5 different database's/a rest api and store in amazon redshift which is based on PostgreSQL 8.3 i believe,

worst case you could always use the delimited file component as well and manually specify your deliminators,

Comment: in this case we have to add tExtractJSON component to the mix and you have the data flowing.